# Смена атрибута href при смене src у картинки при помощи jquery

Tags: jquery, ссылки, атрибуты

Всем привет!
Есть код:

```html
<a href="images/69ca5f6e03.jpg" class="lightzoom">
   <img class="gallery-main-image"  src="images/69ca5f6e03.jpg">
</a>
```

Значение атрибута src у картинки меняется. Как можно сделать так, чтобы значение атрибута href (у ссылки) было равно значению атрибута src (у картинки) при помощи jquery?

Пробовала такой вариант:

```js
$("a.lightzoom").each(function() {
      this.href = $('img', this).attr('src');
 });
```

Работает, но только при загрузке страницы, а мне надо, чтобы срабатывало вместе со сменой значения src

Comment: а значение src у img каким образом меняется? Если при помощи скрипта, то дополните вопрос кодом изменения данного атрибута

Comment: Дело в том, что я пользуюсь шаблоном, в котором весь js в одну строчку написан :), поэтому не могу "выдрать" нужную часть кода.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте по другому: повесьте обработчик на ссылку, и при клике на ссылку проверяйте значение src у тега img и затем делайте переход.

```
$("a.lightzoom").on("click", function() {
  location.href = $(this).find('img.gallery-main-image').attr('src');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Два  замечания: 1. зачем `return false;`? 2. `location.href = $(this).find('img.gallery-main-image').attr('src');`

Comment: Вариантов много может быть, я предложил идею. Потому что, как сейчас поставлена задача, реализовать будет проблематично

Comment: Спасибо, идея хорошая. Но есть еще одна проблема :). При клике на картинку - она должна появляться в popup. Т.е. значение href как раз и нужно для этого popup'а

Comment: @ГалинаВысоцкая - это не имеет отношения к вопросу выше. Задайте, пожалуйста, другой вопрос.

Comment: @Александр Вы оказались правы с `return false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо. 
Я не в том месте искала проблему... Мне главное было, чтобы в popup показывалась та же картинка, что и в превью (это картинка, описанная в моем вопросе с классом gallery-main-image). 
А значения для popup брались из href ссылки с классом lightzoom. 
Короче, поменяла для popup href на src картинки с классом gallery-main-image - всё работает как надо.
Предложенный вариант Александром рабочий, но к моему попапу был не применим. Так как из-за того, что значение в href менялось после клика, показывалась предыдущая картинка.
Извините за некорректный вопрос